# Rails 4 foreign_key is not working with belongs_to

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, jruby

I am using rails 4.2.4 and I want to add a foreign key.

User:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :posts
   validates :name, presence: true
end
```

Post:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :user
   validates :user, presence: true
end
```

Migration:

```
class AddForeignKeysToTables < ActiveRecord::Migration
   def change
      create_table :users do |t|
         t.string   :name
      end

      create_table :posts do |t|
         t.belongs_to :user
      end

     add_foreign_key :posts, :users
   end
end
```

Migration report:

```
 == 20160224131802 AddForeignKeysToRfmAnalyticsTables: migrating ===============
    -- create_table(:users)
       -> 0.0150s
       -> 0 rows
    -- create_table(:posts)
       -> 0.0150s
       -> 0 rows
    -- add_foreign_key(:posts, :users)
       -> 0.0000s
    == 20160224131802 AddForeignKeysToTables: migrated (0.0300s) ======
```

And adding foreign_key in MySQL database is not working without errors. And not one foreign key is created. Do you have any ideas how to create foreign key in this example?

But I want to keep belongs_to in migration, because this is like from old migration, and add_foreign_key has to be a new one migration.

Maybe related gems:

```
jruby_version = '1.7.22'

gem 'rails', '4.2.4'
gem 'activerecord-jdbcmysql-adapter'
```

Also script from schema.rb:

```
create_table "posts", force: :cascade do |t|
   t.integer "user_id", limit: 11
end

create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
   t.string "name", limit: 255
end
```

And also if I am using gems like 'foreigner' or 'foreign_keys', then foreign keys are created, but these gem seems to be incompatible.

Comment: Missing `user_id` in `posts`?

Comment: column user_id is created in posts table... it is just missing foreign key

Comment: btw, column `id` of `users` and `posts` exists?

Comment: yes db support it, MySQL 5.5

Comment: Do you use the `MyISAM` or `InnoDB` database engine? What do you mean by *missing foreign key*? Is there not `FOREIGN KEY CONSTRAINT` on that table in the database or do you only miss it in the `schema.rb`?

Comment: there is no foreign key constraint in schema.rb